# Nested SQL in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am getting below error when I have below SQL for mySQL. Can someone please help me what am I doing wrong. OR Is there any better way to achieive same ?

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(SELECT role FROM `temp_scrconflict` WHERE `release` = 'GROUP6')
>   = ANY (SELECT ' at line 2

```
Select * from `temp_scrconflict`
WHERE ANY (SELECT role
FROM `temp_scrconflict` 
WHERE `release` = 'GROUP6') = ANY (SELECT role
FROM `temp_scrconflict` 
WHERE `release` 
IN ('ER_JUNE15', 'ER_APR15'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it myself, but according to the official documentation:
["The ANY keyword [...] must follow a comparison operator"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Error is in below pointed line. See [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

```
Select * from `temp_scrconflict`
WHERE ANY (SELECT role  <-- Here
```

You need to use a column name along with a comparison operator like

```
where some_column > ANY (subquery)
```

You can modify your query to be like below using `IN` operator

```
Select * from `temp_scrconflict`
WHERE (SELECT distinct role
FROM `temp_scrconflict` WHERE `release` = 'GROUP6') IN (SELECT role
FROM `temp_scrconflict` WHERE `release` IN ('ER_JUNE15', 'ER_APR15'));
```

Comment: problem is both side query needs to be filtered as I am trying to do. I am sure there is better way but not able to think in right direction

Comment: @LordOfTheRing, see edit in answer. I have tried modifying your query using IN operator.

Comment: Now I get error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row